# error in heroku No web processes running python web app

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications

I dont know why this gives an error but everything looks perfect i have tried so many times but this is not working i even gone through the stackoverflow answers nothing helped.I have another app which works fine with this same procfile and port but this gives an error.

**The heroku log looks like this**

```
2018-04-09T08:05:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user vipulrao355@gmail.com
2018-04-09T08:06:32.244340+00:00 app[api]: Deploy cdc01e38 by user vipulrao355@gmail.com
2018-04-09T08:06:32.244340+00:00 app[api]: Release v31 created by user vipulrao355@gmail.com
2018-04-09T08:05:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-04-09T08:09:55.988992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-ridge-58576.herokuapp.com request_id=ca935db6-12ed-4332-ad05-4d7957bebece fwd="106.51.27.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-04-09T08:09:56.406479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-ridge-58576.herokuapp.com request_id=65072529-5e63-4ac1-aa72-990359025bd2 fwd="106.51.27.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**app.py**

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
import clearbit
import json
clearbit.key = 'yourkey'
app = Flask(__name__)

APP__ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/return-file/")
def return_file():

    return send_file('new.csv', as_attachment=True)

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP__ROOT)
    print(target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):
        filename = file.filename
        print(filename)
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)
        new_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
        print(new_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(new_path, sep=',', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    saved_column = df['Company'].dropna()
    i = 0
    res = []
    for data in saved_column:
        n = saved_column.get(i)
        ns = len(n.split())
        if ns > 4:
            n = 'never get a website'
        else:
            print("a")
        i = i + 1
        print(n)
        data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
        print("\n")
        print(data)
        if data != None:
            res.append(data['domain'])
        else:
            res.append('none.com')
    print(res)
    df['Domain'] = res
    print(df['Domain'])
    df.to_csv("new.csv", index=False)
    downloadpath = "new.csv"
    os.remove(os.path.abspath(new_path) )

    return render_template("complete.html", name=downloadpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

**Procfile**

```
web: python app.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the same as the above answer. I copied and pasted all my files into a new folder and then reinitialised the git repo. then git add and commit. and then continued with the heroku commands.

This also happens when 
No Procfile is defined. Or Procfile is defined but has typo-named it like procfile instead of Procfile. or  Procfile has error code in it.

I added my procfile this way instead of manually creating it.:
`echo "web: python app:app" > Procfile`

When you are trying to deploy you will see this error message:

```
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote: 
`Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
remote:  ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
remote: 
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)`
```

if everything goes well while deploying, then it should look like this :

```
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just changed the hosting app and created a new app on heroku and it worked. the error would be the build packs used in it.